# Assigning a specific value to components of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

So far, I've run into this twice and I'm not exactly sure how to make this connection myself, but in this case, I've been asked to find the dot product of $(i+j+k) \cdot (3i+2j-5k)$

I understand everything up until the components dot with themselves. My answer is $(3i^2 + 2j^2 -5k^2)$ And the final answer comes out to be $0$. Can someone explain why $i \cdot i$, $j \cdot j$, and $k \cdot k$ all equal $1$?

Comment: You might explain that $i,j,k$ are vectors of a standard basis (unit vectors). Otherwise your question makes little sense, and it even looks like you are talking about quaternions.

Answer (score 0):

$i,j,k$ are the standard unit vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. Unit vector means of length one. Length is computed by taking the positive square root of the vector dot with itself.